# Azure AD Authentication failing after some time in SIT Environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory, owin, azure-ad-b2b

I have implemented AZure Ad in MVC Application. It works fine in Local Environment.
but after deployment on SIT Environment it works fine 1 Hour.
after it started failing on different browser or incognito mode.
Again when i restart the app it start working.

When it redirected to my redirect-uri i checked there forif (Request.IsAuthenticated)

and it returns false in incognito or some other browser which does't stores cookie for that app.

namespace Abcd
{
    public partial class Startup
    {

```
    // Calling the keys values from Web.config file  
    private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
    private static string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tenant"];
    private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authority"];
    private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUri"];

    // Concatenate aadInstance, tenant to form authority value       
    private string authority = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);


    // ConfigureAuth method  
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(

                        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                        {
                            ClientId = clientId,
                            Authority = authority,
                            RedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                            PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                            {
                                AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                                {
                                    context.HandleResponse();
                                    context.OwinContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/Index");
                                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                                }
                            }
                        });
    } 
}
```

}
i expect it should work for any browser at any time.

Comment: It works fine in Local Environment but on SIT Environment it works fine for some time.  but after some time it does't work on different browser or incognito mode.Again when i restart the app it start working.

Comment: Your question does not have enough details for someone to help. "Not working after some time" will not help anyone to give you any solution.

Comment: its like there is a method Request.IsAuthenticate returning false on SIT Environment it works fine for 1 hour but after that authtication start  failing

Comment: May be the authentication token got expired? Did you check that?